# How can I read my epub books in Google Books for Android?

Tags: ebooks, google-play-books, epub

Has anyone been able to take and place an epub book inside the Google Books app or know how to do it?

Comment: There's a hint that the situation might change soon: The known issues page for Google Play Books NO LONGER lists "Unable to add non-Google eBooks to My Library" as "Working as intended".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[As of March 2013](http://www.engadget.com/2013/05/15/google-play-books-updated-to-allow-user-uploads/?utm_medium=feed&utm_source=Feed_Classic&utm_campaign=Engadget), Google Play Books supports third-party ePub or PDF files. You can upload books to your account by visiting https://play.google.com/books/uploads in your web browser (when logged in to your Google account, of course). You are permitted to store up to 1,000 uploaded files on your account at a time, and each file must be no larger than 50 MB in size.

There are also many alternative book reader apps that support ePub files if you would prefer that. [Aldiko](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aldiko.android&hl=en) seems to be very well liked, but I have not used it myself.

Comment: Aldiko is a front-runner. Great little reader app.

Comment: Another decent epub reader is [Overdrive Media Console](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overdrive.mobile.android.mediaconsole). I haven't compared it to others, but it works for me, and it's what my public library uses for some of it's e-book lending.

Comment: [FBReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android) is a favorite of mine for epubs.

Answer (score 1):

## **You can import/upload them:**

### Uploading the PDF/ePub file(s) to your Library

1. Go to [My Books](https://play.google.com/books)
2. Click on 'Upload File' in the top right corner.
3. Choose the file(s) you wish to upload.

### Getting the PDF/ePub files in your App

1. Go into your [Google Play Books App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books&hl=en).
2. Click on the button on the top left ('Read Now' or 'My Library').
3. Select 'My Library'.
4. Click on the button just underneath it ('All books').
5. Click on 'Uploads'.
6. Click the Android Menu button.
7. Click on 'Refresh'
8. When you try to open the file, you may be prompted to download it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the epub on your device. Use a file manager such as Files to open it (with [Google] Play Books). It'll import it then.

This was tested on Android 10 with the Files file manager (version 1.0.347928958) on a Vastking KingPad SA10 with an epub created with Calibre (3.21.0+dfsg-1build1) for Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, 64-bit, soon before I answered this question.